# Difference between 柱体 and 圆筒

Tags: word-choice, terminology

I get the impression that 柱体 is more mathematical and 圆筒 is more about general "drum shaped" things. Are they interchangeable or is there a distinction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

柱体 is used more in geometry and engineering. It means a column-like body, which can be a square or rectangular column 方柱体, circular column 圓柱体, or any shape of columns.

筒 is a bucket. So 圓筒 is a round bucket or a barrel.

Comment: Nice explanation. It’s important to note 筒 implies hollowness, but not necessarily 柱體.

Comment: @L Parker Mr. Parker, thanks for the note.

Answer (score 3):

(圓)柱體: cylindrical object

圓筒: cylinder

圓筒型 = 圓柱型/狀 = cylindrical

圓筒型物體 = 圓柱型/狀物體 = cylindrical object

Edit:

*Only 圓柱體 is a cylindrical object. There are other forms of 柱體 (column shape objects), e.g. 六角柱體 (hexagonal column-shaped objects), 八角柱體 (octagonal column-shaped objects)*

Comment: In more mathematical terms, 柱體 encapsulates both cylinders and prisms, but not all prismatoids.